# jQuery, display first element in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, html-lists

I am using this JavaScript code to display tweets from twitter:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLwjA/

I want to display one tweet at a time. I can't seem to select the first list item. I tried

`$("ul#twitter_update_list li:first").fadeIn(1000);`

but that didnt work either! I need to know how to fadeOut that first tweet and then fade in the second one.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: As an FYI, jsFiddle will populate the html, head and body tags for you. Just place your contents (raw data) in each box and the bottom-right window will place them in the correct portion of the page.

Comment: The code doesn't work for me :-/

Comment: Ya I dont know why it doesnt fun in jsFiddle, but it works in my browser with the actual files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@thegreyspot: Just change `numTweets` to 1..?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#twitter").getTwitter({
        userName: "thewhitespot",
        numTweets: 1,
        loaderText: "Loading tweets...",
        slideIn: true,
        showHeading: false,
        headingText: "Latest Tweets",
        showProfileLink: false
    });
});
```

**Update**

Working example that fades in each item sequentially: http://jsfiddle.net/SWvPS/1/

**Another update**

Fades in first item then slides it up, then fades in second item before sliding it up as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ErcNA/2/

Comment: Btw, using your account, setting `numTweets` to 2 shows the "latest" one, since the plugin doesn't work for retweets.

Comment: I want to display more than one tweets. But one at a time. Fade in and then out and then in

Comment: @thegreyspot: Ok, I updated my answer (+1 must go to @patrick dw for his `delay()` inspiration)

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution as well

Comment: If you dont mind, can you show me how to show the first one, then remove it, then show the next? I have tried many variation of:                     $(this).hide.delay(i * 1000).fadeIn(3000).delay(i * 1000).remove(); 
 But none seem to work :/ Quite frustrated haha

Comment: @thegreyspot: I've updated my answer with another working example (not sure why considering you've removed my answer's status presumably because I didn't respond to your question within a comment quickly enough).

Comment: @stealthyninja Awesome! Thanks a bunch. It seems to work everywhere I want it to but here: http://173.244.196.144/mbredesign/forum/index.php Any idea why? Sorry, i removed the check mark cause i thought you would never check here again ;) Its back now with a +1

Comment: @thegreyspot: If you look at the response header from Twitter for the plugin's `GET` request, you'll notice the error `Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour`. I suggest you look into caching or limit the plugin from making too many new requests.

Comment: I see, but the problem is that the actual effects are working on that page, when it does get the twitter tweets. I can use the exact same code on that page on a empty page and it works, but something most be conflicting with it on that forum. All it does is fade in and then doesnt rotate

Comment: So I keep getting on this site:http://getmusicbee.com/forum/index.php this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'delay'
$.fn.getTwitterjquery.twitter.js:56
o.extend.speed.E.completejquery.min.js:19
o.fx.stepjquery.min.js:19
Fjquery.min.js:19
o.fx.customjquery.min.js:19

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** To more directly answer your question, to fade in sequentially, do this:

```
$("ul#twitter_update_list li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay( i * 1000).fadeIn(1000); 
});
```

This uses [`delay()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) inside an [`each()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, utilizing the index parameter in the callback to delay the [`fadeIn()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) of each item by `i * 1000` milliseconds.

---

**Original answer:**

Couple problems with your jsfiddle example:

- You need to choose the `jQuery` library from the menu on the left. You currently have `MooTools` selected.
- You are adding the `getTwitter` plugin at `window.onload`, but *calling* the plugin as the page loads. As such, the plugin doesn't exist when you're calling it.

Here's your example, placing your code after the `getTwitter` plugin, and choosing `jQuery` and `onDomReady` from the menus on the left.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mLwjA/12/

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("ul#twitter_update_list li:first-child")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$("ul#twitter_update_list li").eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this one to work. I would like this solution much more. This is what i have: http://jsfiddle.net/XAJTC/7/